# Consum certificate and key from a secret in a route in openshift

Tags: certificate, key, openshift, kubernetes-secrets

How to create a secret with already available certificate and key in openshift, then add it to the route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `oc create secret tls` to create a new `Secret` of type "tls" ([see documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/nodes/pods/nodes-pods-secrets.html)):

```
# Create a new TLS secret named tls-secret with the given key pair:
oc create secret tls tls-secret --cert=path/to/tls.cert --key=path/to/tls.key
```

To create a secured `Route`, you have two options (`reencrypt` or `edge`). For both of these options, you'll want to have your certificate / key as files (certificate/key pair in PEM-encoded files).

1. `reencrypt` will create a `Route` with a custom certificate and reencrypt TLS termination, which means that your OpenShift Router will terminate TLS and then re-encrypt the traffic with the certificate that you specify:

```
$ oc create route reencrypt --service=frontend --cert=tls.crt --key=tls.key --dest-ca-cert=destca.crt --ca-cert=ca.crt --hostname=www.example.com
```

2. `edge` termination means that when you query your application via the `Route`, the OpenShift Router will serve the certificate that you specify:

```
$ oc create route edge --service=frontend --cert=tls.crt --key=tls.key --ca-cert=ca.crt --hostname=www.example.com
```

If you want to read up on the details, check [the documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/networking/routes/secured-routes.html).

Comment: Thank you! where did you tell the route to use the secret tls-secret to get the key and certifcate form it? and key /certificate pair are .pem , should i change that to .key and .crt? in this case how the yml file of the route will look like?

Comment: Not sure if you can use a Secret for a `Route`, as far as I saw you'll need to specify the certificate / key in the Route object as described above. The actual file name does not matter, the certificate / key just need to be PEM-encoded (`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...`).

Answer (score 1):

Routes currently can not access secrets that way.

There is an open issue with a long history(2015):
https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/2162

The [openshift acme operator](https://github.com/tnozicka/openshift-acme) can automatically secure routes, maybe that helps.